# php PDO sqlsrv "could not find driver"

Tags: php, apache-http-server, php5, php.ini

My configuration:
 - Windows Server 2012
 - SQL Server 2012
 - Apache 2.4.9
 - PHP 5.5.10

My php.ini includes the line
 - extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

My "ext" folder includes the file
 - php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

I'm using "php.ini-production" as my php.ini start point.

How can I debug this problem? where can I see if there are any problems to load the extension?

Comment: Do you have 64 bit version of php?

Comment: No, The version WIN32 VC11

Comment: Put your question title in google and see what comes up.I know,not very helpful.

Comment: Do you have installed ODBC 11 or 13?